How to have a row always on top even when using OFFSET?
I'm using Postgres.
I want to have a row always on top (example alias = 'abc') in a query regardless of the offset being used.
Right now, I'm doing
ORDER BY
CASE
    WHEN alias = 'abc' THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END
, avg_xyz
    DESC            
LIMIT 11 OFFSET 10;

but it doesn't work because of OFFSET. Works if OFFSET is 0.

You should include the full query along with some sample data.

As a side-note, order by alias<>'abc' would work without that whole case: boolean false/0 sorts first, so you'll get your 'abc' first, followed by non-'abc', then null: demo

Use two queries:
(SELECT ...
 FROM tab
 WHERE ...
   AND alias = 'abc'
 ORDER BY avg_xyz DESC
 LIMIT 11)
UNION ALL
(SELECT ...
 FROM tab
 WHERE ...
   AND alias IS DISTINCT FROM 'abc'
 ORDER BY avg_xyz DESC
 OFFSET 10 LIMIT 11)
LIMIT 11

